# Fan Issue on DL 380 Gen 7

Tags: fan

I am having an issue with my personal DL380 Gen7. I rebooted the system and it powered back up saying fan 5 failed. I opened the case, looked at the fan and it was not spinning, so I swapped it with fan 1 to see if it was the fan or connector, rebooted the server and now it says fan 1 & fan 5 have failed, neither fan is spinning. Any ideas?

I also swapped the fans back to their original places and when rebooted, still gives fan 1 & fan 5 failed errors.

Answer (score 1):

Motherboard or system board problem.

The system may need repair, but if you configure your ILO, the IML logs will tell you exactly what's broken.